# Apollo client: how to execute a query on custom event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

And its rendering twice on handleclick.

```
import React, {
  useMemo,
  useState,
  useReducer,
  useEffect,
  useCallback,
  Fragment,
} from 'react';

import getAllFaqs from './faqQuery.graphql';
import getFaqById from './getFaqById.graphql';

import FaqTabIndex from './faqTabIndex';
import FaqCategoryList from './faqCategoryList';

import { useFaq } from '../../peregrine/talons/Faq/useFaq';
import { useFaqById } from '../../peregrine/talons/Faq/useFaqById';

const Faq = (props) => {
  const [faq, setFaq] = useState([]);
  const [faqCategory, setFaqCategory] = useState([]);
  const talonProps = useFaq({
    query: getAllFaqs,
  });
  const { data, error, loading } = talonProps;

  useEffect(() => {
    const tempData = { ...data };
    setFaq([...tempData.faq]);
    setFaqCategory([...tempData.faqCategoryList]);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (catId) => {
    const talonProps = useFaqById({
      query: getFaqById,
      id: catId,
    });
    const { data, error, loading } = talonProps;

    console.log('====great data', data);
    useEffect(() => {
      const tempData = { ...data };
      setFaq([...tempData.faq]);
    }, [data]);
  };

  const faqList = faq.length ? (
    <FaqTabIndex items={faq} />
  ) : null;
  const catalog = faqCategory ? (
    <FaqCategoryList
      items={faqCategory}
      handleClick={handleClick}
    />
  ) : (
    nul
  );

  console.log('Thank Faq', faq);
  console.log('Thank Category ', faqCategory);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {faqList}
      {catalog}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Faq;
```

Comment: You seem to be modifying your state within `useEffect`, instead you're supposed to trigger state updates within event handlers

Comment: From what it seems like, useFaqById is a hook and you are using it in handleClick , also useEffect shouldn't be inside handleClick which is probably why you get the error

Comment: Why is the `useEffect` inside `handleClick`, that could be the reason why the error.

Comment: yes useFaqById is a hook and using hook useQuery and return a promise. i want to update my state on action which is done by handleclick.

Comment: Don't initialize hooks inside a handler. Hooks must be initialized once and before any conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to execute query when button is clicked, instead of executing it instantly. That behavior can be implemented by using [lazy query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually).

Try something like this:

**../../peregrine/talons/Faq/useFaqById.jsx**

```js
import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import getFaqById from 'path/to/getFaqById.graphql';
export const useFaqById = useLazyQuery(getFaqById);
```

**Faq.jsx**

```js
const [fetchFaqById, {faqLoading, faqData}] = useFaqById;

const handleClick = (catId) => {
   fetchFaqById({
      variables: {
         id: catId
      }
   });
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (faqData) {
      setFaq([...faqData.faq]);
   }
}, [faqData])
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't call the Query inside handleClick function directly you have to declare only inside the main function after that you have to use.

```
import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import getFaqById from 'path/to/getFaqById.graphql';
const [useFaqById,{data}] = useLazyQuery(getFaqById);
```

Then you can call inside the **handleClick** function

```
const handleClick = (catId) => {
   useFaqById({
      variables: {
         id: catId
      }
   });
}
```